# Задача выполняется только один раз

Tags: java, android, таймер, java-timertask

Решил реализовать в коде обновление информации по API запросу через определенный интервал времени. Сразу по нажатию кнопки информация приходит в соответствующие TextView, потом - тишина. т.е. информация не меняется. За обновление информации отвечает функция `getResponse` - на первоначальном нажатии кнопки информация отдается на экран. Что не так с описание процесса Timer? Интервал обновления стоит 1 секунда.

Вот фрагменты кода по работе с Timer:

Обработчик нажатия кнопки Старт-Стоп:

```
public void didTapButton(View view) {
    if(timer != null){
        timer.cancel();
    }
    if (isEnabled) {


    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        isEnabled = false;
        timer = new Timer();
        mTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
        timer.schedule(mTimerTask,1000);
        getResponse(); //parsing ArtistName & TrackName
    }
    else
    {
        player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        isEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Класс MyTimerTask:

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getResponse(); //parsing ArtistName & TrackName                 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы используете такой вариант метода [shedule](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long)):

```
public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay)
```

В нём второй аргумент отвечает за задержку перед однократным выполнением задачи.

Чтобы сделать выполнение с некоторой периодичностью, нужно использовать метод [shedule](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)):

```
public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```

В нём третьим аргументом будет количество миллисекунд между успешными выполнениями задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Да, действительно, немного видоизменил код, все работает. class Mytimer соответственно остается без изменений. Решение выглядит вот:

```
public void didTapButton(View view) {
    if(timer != null){
        timer.cancel();
    }
    if (isEnabled) {

    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        isEnabled = false;
        timer = new Timer();
        mTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
        timer.schedule(mTimerTask,50, 1000);
        getResponse(); //parsing ArtistName & TrackName
    }
    else
    {
        player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        isEnabled = true;
    }
}
```